# How to display all text from web page in textarea in java jFrame using jsoup ?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jsoup, show

```
private void WebJSoup_jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
 try{
       Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.imdb.com/search/title?groups=top_250&sort=user_rating").userAgent("Mozilla/17.0").get();
       Elements  links=doc.select("h3.lister-item-header");
 int i=0;  
for(Element link:links)
{i++;


 jTextArea1.setText(i+" "+link.getElementsByTag("a").first().text());
}}catch(Exception e){
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
 }

}
```

this is showing only the last movie name. but i want to display all movies name

Comment: Do you want to display full web page in JFrame?

Comment: No. I want to display only movies name. There are 50 movies name in the given url. Right now it display only the last name.

Comment: You a should edit your original question, rather than repeat the same mess in a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a StringBuilder to build a string containig all text you need:

```
private void WebJSoup_jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   try{
         Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.imdb.com/search/title?groups=top_250&sort=user_rating").userAgent("Mozilla/17.0").get();
         Elements  links=doc.select("h3.lister-item-header");
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
         links.stream().forEach(e->sb.append(e.text()).append(System.getProperty("line.separator")));
         jTextArea1.setText(sb.toString());
   }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }

}
```

Comment: Sir Thank You Very Very Much. This is really working. Now all 50 movies are showing in a JFrame by click button. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use append() method instead of setText() like this**

```
jTextArea1.append(additionalText);
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If your are satisfied with my answer then please upvote my answer. Thanks